# MessageBox is modal to the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I'm working on my first WinForms application...I typically write web apps...

A strange thing is happening with my application today.  If I run the application on my computer, or my co-worker runs it on his computer, my MessageBoxes are modal only to my application.  This is the desired behavior.  My users will need to be able to make manual edits in a separate application if a message box appears, and clicking "OK" in the message box will "unpause" my application and allow them to continue.

We just went to install a beta of the application on two end users' computers this afternoon and for some reason when we run the application on either of their computers the message boxes are modal to the desktop - nothing else can receive focus until "OK" is clicked.  This behavior causes a HUGE issue for my application.

I don't know what could be different on the users' machines to cause this behavior.
My computer - Win7 64-bit, my co-worker's computer - Win7 32-bit, two users' computers are Win7 32-bit.  All have .Net Framework 4.5 or 4.5.1 installed.

Any advice?

---

**UPDATES:**

2014.11.17 - code snippet

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The Style field did not pass validation.  
                      Please manually fix the data then click OK to continue.", 
                      "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                      MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Comment: Have you tried the `SetForeGround` function in your MessageBox? `MsgBox("Message", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "Title")`

Comment: @Alex what does MsgBoxSetForeground do?  the short little blurb I found on MSDN doesn't explain it well enough for me.

Comment: It is supposed to do a sort of "Bring to front" with your MessageBox. That way it shouldn't be a modal on your desktop but on the latest app window that was opened. How do you display your message box? What line of code does this?

Comment: @Alex I'll answer questions as updates to the post so we don't have a long conversation in the comments.

Comment: This is technically possible.  The message box window requires an owner window.  If you don't specify it yourself then it will try to find one with GetActiveWindow().  If there is none then it can pick the desktop window, making itself modal to every window that's owned by the desktop.  You have to be doing something *very* strange to not have an active window, you leave no breadcrumbs at all to guess how that happened.  Get ahead by being specific, use the Show() overload that takes an *owner* argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Hans Passant had posted an answer rather than a comment I would've marked his response as the answer.

This is how I resolved the issue:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(t2tWindow, "The Style field did not pass 
                      validation.  Please manually fix the data then click OK 
                      to continue.", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                      MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

This code is in a separate "utility" class, not in the form's code-behind, so I had to pass an `IWin32Window` parameter into the method so I could pass it to the `Show()` method.